# AngularJS authenticating multiple routes with resolve

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, model-view-controller, url-routing

I'm trying to authenticate users for most routes in my application.

Is there a way to do it globally on all routes? so I do not need to have the following:

```
resolve : {
    //This function is injected with the AuthService where you'll put your authentication logic
    'auth' : function(AuthService){
        return AuthService.authenticate();
    }
}
```

on each `$routeProvider.when()` call.

Comment: This [HTTP Auth Interceptor Module](https://github.com/witoldsz/angular-http-auth) may help even if it doesn't fit your need perfectly.

Comment: thanks. that is actually a very helpful approach...

Answer (score 2):

the suggestion by Gloopy was very interesting, and i may implement a similar approach in the future.

For now i have taken a much simpler approach:

```
gm.config(['$routeProvider', 'PathProvider', function($routeProvider, PathProvider) {

    var authResolver = { // although this does work there could be a better way to do this.
        'auth' : function(AuthenticationService) {
            return AuthenticationService.isLoggedIn();
        }
    };

    $routeProvider.when('/authenticatedRoute', { 
        templateUrl: PathProvider.view('application/dashboard/index.html'), 
        controller: 'dashboardController',
        resolve: authResolver
    }); 

    $routeProvider.otherwise({ 
        redirectTo: '/dashboard',
        resolve: authResolver
    });

}]);
```